# creating splash screen

Tags: java, swing, splash-screen

How to create a splash screen as like netbeans or eclipse splash screen. Please help me for this

Regards,

Chandu

Answer (score 5):

Alternatively you can add an entry such as this one:

```
<SplashScreen-Image>images/splash.png</SplashScreen-Image>
```

To your **MANIFEST.MF**. You can have a build tool such as maven add this automatically.

There is also the posibility to simply use a JWindow as a splash screen, but it won't show until the JVM is running. Using the method stacker described(which is the same as the one I point out) you'll show the splash even before the JVM has finished loading, which might be necessary on older hardware.

Comment: Hi, 

Thanks for ur reply. But my requirement is to create a splash screen for a window application that should replicate netbeans or eclipse splash screen.

Please help through a code snippet.

Answer (score 4):

Since java 1.6 you can specify this at the command line

> ```
> java -splash:filename.gif SplashTest
> ```

See this [article](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/J2SE/Desktop/javase6/splashscreen/)

Comment: Hi, Thanks for ur reply. But my requirement is to create a splash screen for a window application that should replicate netbeans or eclipse splash screen. Please help through a code snippet

Answer (score 0):

There is a sample Javafx equivalent of Splash screen. However this splash screen is basically a java swing applet that is called from javafx to be displayed to the user and simulates more or less eclipse and netbeans splash screen using progress bar and titles for the loaded contents. Following is the link 
http://0divides0.wordpress.com/2011/03/17/splash-screen-with-javafx/

You must be able to get the code and seperate out the splash screen code written in java swings and use it for yourself.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the splasher-maven-plugin from www.bitstrings.org to create or edit a splash screen. It may be useful for branding or when you need to overlay some dynamic info like the version or some profile.

Comment: Any link to the plugin? How would this be better than the other options?

Answer (score 0):

If you want a splash screen like a simple image that loads prior to your application, right click in netbeans on the project name, go to properties.  In properties window go to RUN in the last box (VM OPTIONS) paste this:

-splash:src/images/pictureName.jpg

This above assumes you have a java package called images with the image you want in it, you can change the path to where ever you want.